# Grouped Row visibility not filtering based on condition

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have the following condition for row visibility:

```
=IIf(
Fields!DateTime.Value >= DateAdd("d",-7,Today()) 
AND 
Fields!DateTime.Value <= DateAdd("s",-1, DateAdd("d",1,Today()))
,True,False)
```

But for some reason its not working? Well its working but for date ranges more than 7 days, when I want to display only date ranges for the last 7 days not including today.

[image]

Comment: You'll need to add more info. What does your input data look like?, and based on the same data, what do you expect the output to look like?, what are you getting now? Also show the report design and explain where you are setting the `hidden` property, on the row or the rowgroup?

Comment: Do you have the True and False reversed? The property is for when to HIDE the row, not SHOW it.